# Как правильно спарсировать запрос в запросе SQL

Tags: sql

С помощью следующий строчки я получаю колличество нужных мне строк в таблице

```
$total_pages = $connection -> query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followed, questions, languages WHERE questions.id = followed.question_id AND languages.id = questions.language_id AND `user_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '{$_SESSION["user"]["login"]}' )") -> fetch_row()[0];
```

В условии `... WHERE login = '{$_SESSION["user"]["login"]}' ...` я парсирую с помощью фигурных скобок - `'{ ... }'`, и все работает. Как только я парсирую с помощью точек:

```
... WHERE login = " . $_SESSION["user"]["login"] . " ...
```

запрос не работает. Как правильно парсировать с помощью точек?

Comment: В первом варианте вставляемое значение обрамляется одиночными кавычками, что правильно. Во втором - нет, что неправильно.

Comment: Но если я ставлю одинарные кавычки, то переменная получаеться закомментированая, и выдает ошибку

Comment: А если бы пользовались подготовленными запросами, то ничего парсить не нужно было бы. Решаете проблему, которую сами же и создали

Comment: Руками надо делать... и головой.  `... WHERE login = '" . $_SESSION["user"]["login"] . "' ...
`